# How do I use Mercurial to integrate major revisions?

Tags: mercurial

First, I am new to Mercurial and distributed source control systems as a whole. Generally I have used perforce, so I'm going to use perforce terminology in order to keep what I'm trying to say clear.

My issue is that I'm making a game based on an open source engine, and that engine has regular code drops. However, I am also making some changes to the engine code myself, in my own depot. I need to set things up so that I can easily merge changes from code drops in to my own code, without losing my changes, and without having to examine every single file manually.

In Perforce, what I'd do is have a branch for just the engine code, and then my main branch, and all engine code drops would be submitted to the engine code branch, and then I would integrate the engine code branch in to the main code branch. Resolve problems, submit, and voila.

I feel like this is pretty close to how it would work in Mercurial, only I'm missing some minor piece of understanding to help me figure it out. First, I'm not sure if my engine code should be in a branch, or a completely separate repository. And even if I did know that, I'm not clear as to how I'd move code back and forth and keep them properly separate.

Sorry if this is kind of a kitchen sink question. I tend to learn by tossing myself in the deep end.

Comment: Is the "official" version of the engine in Mercurial?

Comment: @robert, I don't understand your question. Your question is akin to "Is the car?", what is your question?

Comment: @Lasse what's not to understand?  Is the "official" version of the game engine in Mercurial?

Comment: @robert No, it's actually in Git, but since I want to be able to control when I integrate new versions, and only want to do large major updates to minimize merging work, I'm cool with just running a local version so I have more control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you could do almost exactly the same thing you do with perforce using named mercurial branches in a single repository:

```
hg branch engine-code
hg ci -m "created engine code branch"
# add the engine code drop
hg ci -m "new drop"
hg update default
hg merge engine-code # merges engine-code drop into your default branch
# test the result of the merge, then commit it:
hg commit -m "merged new engine drop"
```

That's the initial setup.  After that, when you want to add a new drop it's similar:

```
hg update engine-code
# add the new drop
hg ci -m "nother new drop"
hg update default
hg merge engine-code
hg ci -m "merged another new engine drop"
```

Comment: This looks very close to what I am looking for, I think. One question though, since I'm kind of retroactively trying to build this in to my repository, is it possible to create a branch from a really old changelist? I'm looking at the help for hg branch and it doesn't appear to take --rev. Am I over thinking this and will it just work if I `hg update --rev 234` and then do `hg branch` will it just branch from there? (I'd try myself but I'm still new and don't want to muck up the repo)

Comment: Yes, do the `hg update` to the rev you want to branch from and then do `hg branch foo` and then `hg commit -m "created branch foo"` to commit the creation of the branch.

Comment: Also, if you have a repo at a certain point that you know is good and you want to try something you aren't sure about, just clone the known good repo and try your experiment there.  If it works, continue on with the new clone, if it doesn't work, delete the new clone and go back to your known good one.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would separate the engine and the game in two repository. It helps if you want to use the modified engine elsewhere, if you want to contribute back to the original project, if you want to put someone on the engine but not on the game(s),... And to bring them back together, simply use the [`subrepo`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) feature.

Now in the field of the game engine modifications, *as long as there is no conflicting change*, you simply have to `pull`, `merge` then `commit`.

Let's hypothesis a scenario:

```
1----2----4----5---------8----A----B   <---- your changes
      \       /         /         /
       ---3-------6----7----9----/     <---- original changes
```

One day you begin to use the engine (1). The engine is updated (2) but it is ok for you and you use it like that. In fact no, you have to change something (4), in the same time, changed are made on the original one (3). No problem, just fetch them (5) `pull->merge->commit`. Oh, they made a change (6) and another one (7). OK, let's include them (8) `pull->merge->commit`. And so on, they made changes (9), you make changes (A) and you merge them (B).

One unnatural thing to remember when switching from centralized to distributed version control is that branching and merging is a normal (and lightweight) process, not an exceptional one. Some people merge hundreds of time per day.

For more understanding try to search for "mercurial workflow" (here I exposed a minimal one) and read the excellent book [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/) by Bryan O'Sullivan

### Follow up about comments

Consider a minimal project like this one:

```
mygame/
├── .hg/
├── .hgsub
├── lib/
│   └── engine/
│       ├── enginefile.cpp
│       └── .hg/
├── mygame.proj
└── src/
    └── mygamefile.cpp
```

And now your comments:

> Also, I would like to be able to work
>   on all my game's content in the same
>   repository[...]

If I understand well, in fact, you want to "be able to work on all [your] game's content in the same [project]". Correct me if I made a false guess.

Here, the two directories containing a `.hg` subdirectory are separate repositories (`mygame` and `engine`). But you can nest them without making separated projects in your IDE.  So two nested repositories, but only one project. In your build configuration (`Makefile`s, solutions, ...), you can even make references from `mygame` to `engine` as the `engine` sub-repository is always present (typically to use headers from the engine in your game).

> [...] would it be possible to get it
>   slightly more specific? Example
>   commands, repositories, paths, etc?

- For the paths, look at the second figure.
- To update the engine, in the `engine` directory (`cd lib/engine`): `hg pull`, `hg merge`, `hg commit -m "merge new original with my modifications"`, `cd ..`, `hg commit -m "updated to new engine version"`, now you have the new version with your changes included.
- For other basic use, it looks like other version control system. In your case, [this](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PerforceConcepts) article could be useful to map perforce to mercurial commands.

Comment: Thank you, this sheds a bit of light on the subject, but would it be possible to get it slightly more specific? Example commands, repositories, paths, etc?

Comment: Also, I would like to be able to work on all my game's content in the same repository, so game and engine, for convenience. I am not clear how a sub-repo would work in this case, as I think I would need three repositories, the 'clean' original engine repository, the 'sub repo' that houses/mirrors my own changes, and then my own repo itself?

Comment: I want it in the same project *and* the same repository, so that if I make a change which affects both engine and game, I don't have to do two sets of commits/pushes.

Comment: @CharlesRandall: For the commit/push part of your comment, when they are done from main repository, it also commit/push the subrepo, so no need to do it twice. If you really want a single repository, it is possible, but I would consider that a bad practice.

Comment: @CharlesRandall: even better for your case as you indicated that the engine is in git. From version 1.8 of mercurial, you can use git repositories as subrepo.

Comment: @shellholic Okay, that does actually start to sound more useful, especially since I'd want to maintain my own github version of the engine so that I can push back. 

With that in mind though, would I still be able to change branches on just the subrepo without having those branches line up exactly with the full repo? 

I guess I'll look in to doing it this way.

Comment: On a closer look at subrepos, this really isn't what I want. I don't necessarily want the two repos to be in lock step, since A) I don't necessarily want to push back to my engine repo at the same time I commit to my game repo, and B) even if I did, I wouldn't want commit messages for game stuff to end up in the engine repo. So that leaves micromanaging all my commits so that they are properly seperate, even though the same commits, pushes, and pulls, will be propagated down the chain.

Comment: Also, one last issue, is that the code layout of a project using the engine isn't the same as the engine layout itself, since projects actually use a subset of what's in the engine. I thank you for all your effort and help, you've made me look at things in new ways but ultimately I think I'm going to just use basic branching to do it.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called a "vendor branch" -- a branch where you keep the clean code drops from your upstream vendor. You then make your own modifications in another branch and regularly merge in code drops that you have put into the vendor branch. Very much like you described it yourself in the question how krupan described it in his answer.

I have written a set of [slides that explain how vendor branches work Mercurial](https://bitbucket.org/mg/mercurial-talk/downloads/vendor-branches.pdf). You should be able to follow them with your Perforce background. Searching the Mercurial mailinglist for "vendor branch" also [shows many good hits](http://mercurial.markmail.org/search/?q=vendor%20branch).

Comment: Thank you, this, coupled with the explicit commands from @krupan, finally helped me solve this issue.

Comment: You're welcome -- I wanted to give you the right keyword ("vendor branch") to search for.